# Is there a compiler flag to make newer gcc versions build like old ones did?

Tags: c++, gcc, build, msys2

I am using MSys2/MinGW on Windows 7 to build an old project.  MSys2 only uses the latest version of gcc and building the project with gcc v9.1.0 fails because it can't find an overloaded "<<" operator.

Through trial and error (and Cygwin), I have found that gcc v6.4.0 builds the project and v7.x does not.

Is there a CCFLAGS or CXXFLAGS option that I can use to make gcc v9.1.0 behave as if it was v6.4.0?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to find out Why _it can't find an overloaded "<<" operator_ and fix the problem? It might be caused by hidden [U.B.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939) in code which only accidentally worked in the older compiler. (I had such a case when we switched from VS2008 to VS2013. The actual reason was wrong use of a `std::set` which was uncovered in the newer compiler (where it simply failed to compile).)

Comment: Technically, yes.  We have managed to get past this problem with a Cygwin build, but I'd like to solve the build error in a way that does not alter the source files.  If no gcc flags exist for this purpose, then the source code will be updated.

Comment: Have you tried to change the C++ standard by using command line arg. `-std`? May be, it's worth to expose the actual error message for the not found `operator<<`. Is it one of the `std` library or a custom?

Comment: Yes.  There is a `-std=c++11` flag in the CXXFLAGS.

Comment: It's a custom template, which refers to an overloaded method further down the same file.  I can't provide the example, unfortunately.

Comment: _I can't provide the example, unfortunately._ That's wrong. You don't need to expose your code. (You shouldn't.) Just resemble the issue in a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can tell GCC to use an older C/C++ standard using the `-std=` compiler flag, for example the `g++` option `-std=c++11` to make it conform to to the ISO 2011 C++ standard.

To get a list of all possible `-std=` command line flags run:

`g++ --help -v 2>/dev/null|grep std=`

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if this cannot be solved with compiler flags, so the answer to the question is "no".

**Workaround:** If you are in a position where you cannot modify the source code and you're compiling under Windows, then download a specific version of the MinGW toolchain using the MinGW Installer Utility from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe).  This lets you choose which version of GCC to install.

You can still use an MSys/MinGW shell if you change your PATH variable to put the new MinGW install directory first by adding a line like this to your `.profile`:

`export PATH=/c/mingw-w64/x86_64-6.4.0-win32/mingw64/bin:$PATH`

Comment: In https://winlibs.com/ there are also different GCC versions available as standalone packages. They have no installation procedure (just unzip) and so allow coexistence of multiple versions on one system (as long as you don't add anything to the `PATH` environment variable).